# How to show image dynamically in ASP.NET literal Control

Tags: javascript, asp.net

The following code does not work:

```
literalNews.Text = "<img id='Image3' src='~/images/news_li.gif' alt=' ' height='20' width='20' />";
```

Comment: Bind an image tag inside the literal `<a id='img' src='[path]'></a>`. Thats it!

Comment: What you have won't work as `'~/images/etc` needs to have the path resolved.

Comment: what Jon P means is that you could try to remove the '~' from '~/images/news_li.gif'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, this works fine on me.. :)

```
literalNews.Text = "<img id='Image3' src='../images/news_li.gif' alt=' ' height='20' width='20' />";
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your context is a page you need to resolve `~/` as it is a .net construct, it enables code to be used at different levels of a website.

Try

```
string src = Page.ResolveUrl("~/images/news_li.gif"); 
literalNews.Text = string.Format("<img id='Image3' src='{0}' alt=' ' height='20' width='20' />", src);
```

Your other option is to use a root relative path

```
literalNews.Text = "<img id='Image3' src='/images/news_li.gif' alt=' ' height='20' width='20' />";
```